# Pre-registering users in database with python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, google-oauth

I'm using python-social-auth for user login for my organization site. I only allow Google accounts in a white list (the people in my organization) to login to the site. However, I would like to preregister everyone in the database so that I can add their custom fields (leadership positions, etc.). Is it possible to add user accounts before their first login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using pipelines in python-social-auth.

Create a custom pipeline by creating pipeline.py file and add your functions here.
A simple example of functions can be found [here](http://www.masnun.com/2014/01/03/python-social-auth-custom-pipeline.html)

Comment: Well I finally made an account yesterday so I don't have the reputation yet. I'll upvote when that happens!